# Glassfish 3.1 management through REST API using JSON

Tags: json, rest, glassfish, glassfish-3

I am attempting to send JSON (or XML, either would be fine) to a local Glassfish server to help with management. It is very unclear what to actually put in your JSON/XML, however. For example when sending a POST request to http://localhost:4848/management/domain/update-password-alias using the following JSON

```
{"Message parameters": [{"id":"f"},{"AS_ADMIN_ALIASPASSWORD":"b"}]}
```

I get the following result

```
Cannot find aliasName in update-password-alias command model, file a bug
injection failed on com.sun.enterprise.security.cli.UpdatePasswordAlias.aliasName with class java.lang.String</h3>
    <h2>Create update-password-alias command
```

So it seems I'm sending some bad JSON. I've been looking through the entire Oracle documentation which is provided, but there are seemingly no decent examples which show what format is actually expected.

Answer (score 1):

After much experimentation, I finally found an answer. To do it in JSON, you can simply use the following code, for example:

```
{"id":"g","AS_ADMIN_ALIASPASSWORD":"c"}
```

Slightly unrelated (and in case I ever find my own post back), be sure to add the following header:

```
X-Requested-By: GlassFish REST HTML interface
```

Comment: You might find Adam Bien's [Lightfish](http://lightfish.adam-bien.com/) interesting. It's a monitoring tool which uses the REST interface to gather data. [The source is available on his Github](https://github.com/AdamBien/lightfish)